# Firebase Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating a simple library app where books can be added and a list of books can be viewed.

here is my book class

```
public class Book {

private int _id;
private String _bookTitle;
private String _bookAuthor;
private int _bookISBN;

private Map<String, Object> mp;

public Book() {

}

public Book(String _bookTitle, String _bookAuthor, int _bookISBN) {
    this._id = _id;
    this._bookTitle = _bookTitle;
    this._bookAuthor = _bookAuthor;
    this._bookISBN = _bookISBN;

}

public int get_id() {
    return _id;
}

public void set_id(int _id) {
    this._id = _id;
}

public String get_bookTitle() {
    return _bookTitle;
}

public void set_bookTitle(String _bookTitle) {
    this._bookTitle = _bookTitle;
}

public String get_bookAuthor() {
    return _bookAuthor;
}

public void set_bookAuthor(String _bookAuthor) {
    this._bookAuthor = _bookAuthor;
}

public int get_bookISBN() {
    return _bookISBN;
}

public void set_bookISBN(int _bookISBN) {
    this._bookISBN = _bookISBN;
}


public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
    mp = new HashMap<>();
    mp.put("bookTitle", this._bookTitle);
    mp.put("bookAuthor", this._bookAuthor);
    mp.put("bookISBN", this._bookISBN);


    return mp;
} }
```

and here is where I am trying to read from the values which are already written into firebase

[image: snapshot of firebase]

```
public class ViewBook extends AppCompatActivity {


ArrayList<String> myArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference();
//  DatabaseReference mPostReference = ref.child("books");
DatabaseReference temp = ref.child("books");

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();


    ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Book book = postSnapshot.getValue(Book.class);

                myArrayList.add(book.get_bookTitle() + "\n" + book.get_bookAuthor()  + "\n" + book.get_bookISBN());


            }

            ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ViewBook.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myArrayList);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            //Getting Post failed, log a message
            Log.w("VIEWBOOKS", "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());

        }
    };
    temp.addValueEventListener(postListener);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_book);
}}
```

the error I am getting is

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.taylorcampos.androidfirebasedatabase, PID: 25339
              com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.taylorcampos.androidfirebasedatabase.Book
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zze(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zzb(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zza(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
                  at com.example.taylorcampos.androidfirebasedatabase.ViewBook$1.onDataChange(ViewBook.java:38)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbpx.zza(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqx.zzZT(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbra$1.run(Unknown Source)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Someone please explain why this is happening and how I could get the list view to list these books that have been put into firebase.

Comment: Your "books" is actually a single `Book`. Your code fails when you try to convert `bookAuthor` (which is String) to `Book` (which is not string and can't be read from String. Your `books` should contain an array of JsonObjects for your code to work.

Answer (score 1):

`dataSnapshot.getChildren()` is going to return you a list of attributes for a book, not a `Book` object itself. One of those is a String, thus the error

You need another level of data in the database, or if all you're storing is a list of books, remove `child("books")` and use a generated unique  key instead of the string `"books"`

Additionally, Firebase is going to try to set your fields using `camelCase` methods and variables (like those in the database), not underscores like those in your Java class. In other words, they should match

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference();
DatabaseReference temp = ref.child("books");
```

Updated code with correction to solve error:

```
DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference();
DatabaseReference temp = ref.child("books").toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your doing it wrong this is how you get it
databasereference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("books")
if you have a child on that then just add
.child( "like fuser.getUid() something like this" )

once that's done then add a Listener for it, now go to onDataChange add your code like this
String userName = snapshot.child("Data Name").getValue().toString();